# How can I push data to an array with fixed length in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have an array of object something like this.

```
[
 {
    channelName: "WhatsApp"
    count: 1
    date: "2021-06-05"
 },{
 channelName: "RCS"
 count: 1
 date: "2021-06-09"
}
]
```

There are two types of channel names 1. WhatsApp and 2nd are RCS. I want to filter out count with specific channel names and store it in a separate array. But the problem here is I want both the array length should be the same. If there is data for WhatsApp then it will add the count otherwise it will add 0 in place of it.

For that, I did something like this but this does not work .

```
const filterData = (data: any) => {
    const category: any = [];
    const whatsAppCount: any = [];
    const rcsCount: any = [];
    data.filter((item: any, i: number) => {
      if (item.channelName === "WhatsApp") {
        whatsAppCount[i] = item.count;
      } else if (item.channelName === "RCS") {
        rcsCount[i] = item.count;
      }
      category.push(item.date);
    });
    setGraphData({
      category: category,
      whatsApp: whatsAppCount,
      rcs: rcsCount,
    });
    console.log("handleRun", { category, whatsAppCount, rcsCount });
  };
```

Here the console log gives something like this.

```
whatsAppCount: [1, 2, 13, 21, empty × 2, 8, 5, empty, 18, empty, 12, 4]
rcsCount: [empty × 4, 1, 12, empty × 2, 1, empty, 8]
```

Here in the place of empty, I want 0. I am not sure how to do that any help would be great.

Comment: Can you update your input example so we can see why you're getting that output?

Comment: I think you should have a look at my answer, even you accept it. It is not necessary to initialize an empty array in the beginning.

Comment: @ikhvjs I tried your answer but in my case, it did not work as expected.

Comment: I have to display these data on a line graph and have to store Them in a separate array that why may be your answer did not work in my case.

Comment: OK. I thought my answer should help you. I think the reason is I ```push(null)``` for the empty record before. I updated my answer to ```push(0)``` instead. It should work. It is fine not to accept my answer, but it is really not necessary to create a empty array for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the arrays, but before populating them, there are two functions that can help with initialization:

```
// create an array with 10 slots preallocated but empty (not `undefined`)
let arr = new Array(10);

// set all allocated slots to a value (`0` in this case)
arr = arr.fill(0);
```

Since you know the lengths you want ahead of time, you can use that to pre-size the arrays on construction. Then use `.fill` to initialize the values to `0`. Once, that's done, you can continue with your counting and updating the arrays.

Reference:

- [Array constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array)
- [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the `map`-function, mapping the unwanted values to `undefined`, letting the other values "pass through" (unmodified), eg.:

```js
const filtered = data.map((each) => {
   if (wantToKeep) {
      return each;
   } else {
      return undefined;
   }
});
```

Note, this is not the exact solution - but a general idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` and `push(0)` for the empty records.

```js
const data = [
  {
    channelName: "WhatsApp",
    count: 1,
    date: "2021-06-05",
  },
  {
    channelName: "RCS",
    count: 1,
    date: "2021-06-01",
  },
  {
    channelName: "RCS",
    count: 1,
    date: "2021-06-06",
  },
  {
    channelName: "WhatsApp",
    count: 5,
    date: "2021-06-11",
  },
  {
    channelName: "WhatsApp",
    count: 7,
    date: "2021-06-23",
  },
  {
    channelName: "RCS",
    count: 1,
    date: "2021-06-09",
  },
];
const category = [];
const whatsAppCount = [];
const rcsCount = [];

data.forEach(x => {
  if (x.channelName === "WhatsApp") {
    whatsAppCount.push(x.count);
    rcsCount.push(0);
  } else if (x.channelName === "RCS") {
    whatsAppCount.push(0);
    rcsCount.push(x.count);
  }

  category.push(x.date);
});

console.log({ whatsAppCount });
console.log({ rcsCount });
console.log({ category });
```